# Bootstrap table issue with 17 <th> columns, not being responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a simple boostrap table which i have 17 `<th>`, The problem is that they can't fit properly next to each other. Because of the reason bootstrap being responsive this happens.. But all i want to do is: if the the `<th>` columns are a lot like my example 17.. i want the google chrome down side bar to appear and just scroll left/right and see eveything.. Is this possible?
I will leave a snippet in order to see.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Βάση πελατών</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid shadow py-3 my-3">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">name</th>
            <th scope="col">lastname</th>
            <th scope="col">password</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Entry to the control panel</th>
            <th scope="col">payment</th>
            <th scope="col">Home telephone</th>
            <th scope="col">mobile telephone</th>
            <th scope="col">Τ.Κ.</th>
            <th scope="col">AFM</th>
            <th scope="col">Job</th>
            <th scope="col">Δ.Ο.Υ.</th>
            <th scope="col">Website - Webpage - Office</th>
            <th scope="col">Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggg</th>
            <th scope="col">Comments</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
       

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the `Entry to the control panel` and `Website - Webpage - Office` is Terrible

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly,  `th {white-space: nowrap}`?

Comment: @pavel yes, This is what i wanted! Consider Answering my question in order to Accept it and take the poionts. Also sry for my bad english feel free to edit my question, in order to help more people if they ever come across with this issue.

Comment: Glad to helped you. I don't answer here for getting more reputation, I don't need to rewrite again as an answer ;-)